# Whats the difference between SELECT attribute FROM table and table.attribute?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables

- Employee(eid, salary)
- Onproject(pid, eid)

I need to calculate the difference between the average salary of workers on projects and who not working on projects.
When i execute this Query:

```
WITH worksOnProjects(avgSalary) AS (
  SELECT AVG(salary)
  FROM Employee AS e, 
       Onproject
  WHERE e.eid IN (SELECT eid 
                  FROM Onproject)
), notWorksOnProjects(avgSalary) AS (
   SELECT AVG(salary)
   FROM Employee AS e, 
        Onproject
   WHERE e.eid NOT IN (SELECT eid 
                       FROM Onproject) 
)
SELECT w.avgSalary - n.avgSalary
FROM notWorksOnProjects AS n,
     worksOnProjects AS w
```

Everything is fine. But when I execute this Query:

```
WITH worksOnProjects(avgSalary) AS (
  SELECT AVG(salary)
  FROM Employee AS e, 
       Onproject
  WHERE e.eid IN (Onproject.eid)
), notWorksOnProjects(avgSalary) AS (
  SELECT AVG(salary)
  FROM Employee AS e, 
       Onproject
  WHERE e.eid NOT IN (Onproject.eid )
)
SELECT w.avgSalary - n.avgSalary
FROM notWorksOnProjects AS n,
     worksOnProjects AS w
```

I get other result.

Can someone explain me the difference between

`SELECT eid FROM Onproject` and `Onproject.eid`?

What's happening behind the scenes?

Comment: I am unsure that your queries do make sense. Would you please show us sample data and expected results?

Comment: Why all the cross-joins?